# Checkboxes and button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="five columns">
<a class="button small primary right" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    Опубликовать выбранное
</a>
```

and I have this:

```
<td>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox"/></p>
</td>
```

I need the following: if I click on the button and some of these check-boxes are checked, then some action is executed. How can I do this?
It's in FTL file

Comment: 'some of this checkboxes is checked' what do mean by this? do you want to say atleast one checkbox checked?

Comment: i can't see any button control in your code.

Comment: Your `<input />` element isn't closed. And you need to give some idea of what you want to happen? Should a function be called? The same function regardless of which checkbox  is, or how many are, checked? Also, what have you tried, can we see your attempt (s)? They might help us understand your aims better, but as it stands this question is difficult to answer usefully because we don't know quite what you want.

Comment: I think you'll need to re-read your question and edit it a bit to make it a clearer. I'm not really sure what you're asking for at the moment.

Comment: @AmitKumar it seems that `<a class="button small primary right">` is this so called button (at least because it has text "publish selected")

Comment: Friend, you have only one checkbox in your code. How can you say this line- some of these check-boxes are checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function{

jQuery(".button").click(function(){
  //your action

})
if(jQuery('td checkbox').is(':checked')){

  //your action
}

});
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: Please like my Answer if it was helpful :)